# python program doesn't read text file and doesn't put the words in the list

Tags: python

I want the program to read a text file and to put every word in a list, here's the code that I've written:

```
class Teater(object):
    def__init__(self, namn, AntalPlatser, VuxenBiljettpris, 
            PensionärBiljettpris, BarnBiljettpris, 
            vuxen=0, pansionär=0, barn=0):

        self.namn=namn
        self.AntalPlatser=AntalPlatser
        self.VuxenBiljettpris=VuxenBiljettpris
        self.PensionärBiljettpris=PensionärBiljettpris
        self.BarnBiljettpris=BarnBiljettpris
        self.vuxen=vuxen
        self.barn=barn
        self.pansionär=pansionär


def teaterLista():
    infil = open("teatrar.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
    lista=[]
    lista = lista[4:]
    for rad in lista:
        splitList=rad.split("/")
        namn=splitlist[0]
        AntalPlatser=splitlist[1]
        VuxenBiljettpris=splitlist[2]
        PensionärBiljettpris=splitlist[3]
        BarnBiljettpris=splitlist[4]
        nyTeater = Teater(
            namn, 
            AntalPlatser, 
            VuxenBiljettpris, 
            PensionärBiljettpris,
            BarnBiljettpris)
        lista.append(nyTeater)
    return lista
```

and my text file looks like this:

```
Såda Teaterbiljetter
TeaternsNamn/Antal platser i salongen/Vuxenbiljettpris/Pensionärbiljettpris/Barnbiljettpris
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

SodraTeatern/414/330/260/200 

Dramaten/770/390/350/100 

ChinaTeatern/1230/395/300/250
```

I don't want the first 4 rows of the text file to be printed. but when I type läsFil() in python Shell i only get this: [ ]

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This is crucial in python.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code, but most notably you don't ever read from the file `infil`. Instead you create an empty list and take a slice on that list, so it is still empty:

```
lista=[]
lista = lista[4:]
```

Anyway, you should have a look at the [CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, which can handle for you the reading of delimited text files (whether separated by commas or slashes).

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code looks very suspicious:

```
infil = open("teatrar.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")  # not used after.
lista=[]
lista = lista[4:]  # does nothing since lista is empty
for rad in lista:
```

You probably mean:

```
infil = open("teatrar.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
lista=[]
for rad in infil:
```

Then

```
namn=splitlist[0]
AntalPlatser=splitlist[1]
VuxenBiljettpris=splitlist[2]
PensionärBiljettpris=splitlist[3]
BarnBiljettpris=splitlist[4]
```

Could be better written as

```
namn, AntalPlatser, VuxenBiljettpris, PensionärBiljettpris,  BarnBiljettpris =  splitlist[:5]
```